# Python vertical stack not working

Tags: python, numpy

I have a matrix X which has `len(X)` equal to 13934 and `len(X[i])`, for all i, equal to 74, and I have an array Y which has `len(Y)` equal to 13934 and `len(Y[i])` equal to `TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int64' has no len()` for all i.

When I try `np.vstack((X,Y))` or `result = np.concatenate((X, Y.T), axis=1)`

I get `ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`

What is the problem?

When I print out Y it says array([1,...], dtype=int64) and when I print out X it says array([data..]) with no dtype. Could this be the problem?

I tried converting them both to float32 by doing `X.view('float32')` and this did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `X` is a numpy array, you can do `X.shape` instead of the repeated `len`.  I expect it to show (13934, 74).

I expect `Y.shape` to be (13934,). It's a 1d array, which is why `Y[0]` is a number, `numpy.int64`.  And since it is 1d, transpose (swapping axes) doesn't do anything.  (this isn't MATLAB where everything has at least 2 dimensions.)

It looks like you want to create an array that has shape (13934, 75).  To do that you'll need to add a dimension to `Y`.  `Y[:,None]` is a concise way of doing that.  The shape of that is (13934,1), which will concatenate with `X`.  If that `None` syntax is puzzling, try, `Y.reshape(-1,1)` (or `reshape(13934,1)`).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
# use Y[:,None] to make Y 2d array so it can be concatenated with X which is also 2d
np.concatenate((X, Y[:,None]), axis=1)
```

Or:

```
np.hstack((X,Y[:,None]))
```